# response with [object object] in JSON

Tags: jquery, json

When i execute my page with JSON always have this response: `[object object]`. i have read in other post is a problem with not exist field, but this error appear too comment

```
$.each(result, function(i, row) { 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row)); 
    $('#data-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id+ '"><h3>' + row.nombre + '</h3><p>' + row.denominacion + '</p></a></li>');
});
```

My javascript is:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){      
            var stuff = {
              id:null,
              nombre:null,
              precio:null,
              denominacion:null
              };
            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(stuff);

     $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.domain.com/ws.php?TIPO=OK" ,
          crossDomain: true,
            type:"GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
                async: true,
                data: jsonString,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    $.each(result, function(i, row) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
                    $('#data-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id+ '"><h3>' + row.nombre + '</h3><p>' + row.denominacion + '</p></a></li>');
                     });
                $('#data-list').listview('refresh');
                },
                error:  function(xhr, status, error){
                          console.log(status + '; ' + error+ ';');},
                jsonpCallback:function(response) {
                          console.log('callback success'+response);
              }
            });         
        });
```

In webserver is very simple only do a select and encapsule in JSON , i try with Content-type: application/javascript" and "Content-type: application/json" but same result,this is web service code

```
<?php
    include($DIRCONF . 'conf/VARIABLES.ini.php'); //incluimos configuración
    include($DIRCONF . 'JSON.php'); $tipo=$_GET['TIPO']; $json = new Services_JSON;

$conexion = mysql_connect(SERVIDOR_MYSQL, USUARIO_MYSQL, PASSWORD_MYSQL); mysql_select_db(BASE_DATOS, $conexion);

$que = "SELECT * FROM `DATOS`";

$res = mysql_query($que, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $data[] = $row; } //Cerramos la conexion a la base de datos mysql_close($conexion);


//header("Content-type: application/javascript"); header("Content-type: application/json"); echo json_encode($data) ; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can find solution problem was Webservice, If you use jsonp: 'jsoncallback' need in WS return $_GET['jsoncallback'] how JSON object, if not put it, don't find any object and do error.

For example:

```
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
```

Answer (score 1):

`[object object]` is what JavaScript gives you when you attempt to use an object as if it were a string. It is possible that your code is fine, but `console.log('callback success'+response);` is never going to log useful information. This *might* work:

```
console.log('callback success: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
```

Comment: console.dir might also be an option

Comment: which this log show "callback success:undefined"
page.html.html (línea 44) (Line of log)

parsererror; Error: undefined was not called;[object Object], what mean this, men arrive function callback not defined values???
page.html (línea 41) (This line is where is function error)